# Using ASP.NET Cryptography in ASP Classic application

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

It looks like I might need to port an older web application to a cloud platform ([Rackspace Cloud Sites](http://cloud.rackspace.com)). While this would put me on the latest version of IIS, it also means that I won't be able to install any custom COM components.

I use one such component for basic cryptography right now, but the Rackspace environment doesn't have anything approximating that. Then I thought of the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace in ASP.NET.

The one solution I've pictured so far would require me to POST values from my ASP Classic script to an ASP.NET page that would return an encrypted string. I'm concerned about the performance implications of this approach. Should I be?

Are there any other ways to integrate the two without relying on POSTS?

Answer (score 1):

How frequently do you need to call the crypto functions?

Your best bet in such a restricted hosting environment is probably to have a .NET webservice setup and call that via XmlHttp from the ASP page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do Server.Transfer() from classic asp?  That way you could execute the aspx page from the asp and get the response without all the extra browser trips.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Server.Transfer` from Classic ASP to ASP.NET will lose all session state, just a `Response.Redirect` would.